# How do I separate letters and digits in python?

Tags: python, text

I have this line

> HL1110/1110R/1112/1112R/MFC1810/1810R/1815/1815R/DCP1510/1510R/1512/1512R

As you can see some of them have HL or a couple of other letters, which means that 1110R is also from HL Series,

I'm trying to divide the line with "/" and then look for strings, but then, I need to speared HL from 1110, how do I do it? Check with isinstance(x,str) gives me true with both values(H or 1), So how do I separate them as strings and digit?

Comment: what would be the output of processing that line ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = "HL1110/1110R/1112/1112R/MFC1810/1810R/1815/1815R/DCP1510/1510R/1512/1512R"
>>> for item in s.split("/"):
...     print ["".join(g) for k,g in groupby(item, str.isdigit)]
... 
['HL', '1110']
['1110', 'R']
['1112']
['1112', 'R']
['MFC', '1810']
['1810', 'R']
['1815']
['1815', 'R']
['DCP', '1510']
['1510', 'R']
['1512']
['1512', 'R']
```

Comment: What if I want to have this output?
['HL','1110','1110R','1112','1112R']
['MFC','1810','1810R','1815','1815R']
['DCP','1510','1510R','1512','1512R']
How do I get it?

Answer (score 4):

strings have a very nice `isdigit` method that you can use.

```
>>> 'H'.isdigit()
False
>>> '1'.isdigit()
True
>>> '10'.isdigit()
True
```

Comment: Also an analog to this `isalpha()`

Answer (score 3):

You can separate using `isdigit()`. For instance, using list comprehension:

```
>>> s = "HL1110/1110R/1112/1112R/MFC1810/1810R/1815/1815R/DCP1510/1510R/1512/1512R"
>>> [i for i in s.split('/')]
['HL1110', '1110R', '1112', '1112R', 'MFC1810', '1810R', '1815', '1815R', 'DCP1510', '1510R', '1512', '1512R']
>>> [i for i in s.split('/') if i.isdigit()]
['1112', '1815', '1512']
>>> [i for i in s.split('/') if not i.isdigit()]
['HL1110', '1110R', '1112R', 'MFC1810', '1810R', '1815R', 'DCP1510', '1510R', '1512R']
```

Using [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) is equivalent:

```
>>> filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(), s.split('/'))
['1112', '1815', '1512']
>>> filter(lambda x:not x.isdigit(), s.split('/'))
['HL1110', '1110R', '1112R', 'MFC1810', '1810R', '1815R', 'DCP1510', '1510R', '1512R']
```

Alternatively, if you want only some of the strings, you can use a different condition in the if part. In order to have only strings with 'R' or 'HL', just change the if condition:

```
>>> [i for i in s.split('/') if ('R' in i) or ('HL' in i)]
['HL1110', '1110R', '1112R', '1810R', '1815R', '1510R', '1512R']
```

Comment: What if I want to have this output?
['HL','1110','1110R','1112','1112R']
['MFC','1810','1810R','1815','1815R']
['DCP','1510','1510R','1512','1512R']
How do I get it?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to break the series component out:

```
from pprint import pprint
import re

line = 'HL1110/1110R/1112/1112R/MFC1810/1810R/1815/1815R/DCP1510/1510R/1512/1512R'

result = {}
series = ''
for item in line.split('/'):
  match = re.match(r'(\D*)(.*)', item)
  if not match:
    print '%s: bad form?'%item
    continue
  i,j = match.groups()
  if i:
    series = i
  result.setdefault(series, []).append(j)
pprint (result)
```

Another way, using `re.findall()` instead of `re.match()`:

```
from pprint import pprint
import re

line = 'HL1110/1110R/1112/1112R/MFC1810/1810R/1815/1815R/DCP1510/1510R/1512/1512R'

series = None
result = {}
for maybe_series, item in re.findall('([A-Z]*)([^/]+)', line):
  series = maybe_series or series
  result.setdefault(series, []).append(item)
pprint (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`re` can split them into lists of ints and strings:

```
import re

s = "HL1110/1110R/1112/1112R/MFC1810/1810R/1815/1815R/DCP1510/1510R/1512/1512R"

ints  = re.findall("\d+",s) # one or more digits
st = re.findall("[A-Z]+",s) # one or more uppercase  letters 

print ints,st
['1110', '1110', '1112', '1112', '1810', '1810', '1815', '1815', '1510', '1510', '1512', '1512'] ['HL', 'R', 'R', 'MFC', 'R', 'R', 'DCP', 'R', 'R']
```

If you want a list of ints:

```
print map(int,ints)
[1110, 1110, 1112, 1112, 1810, 1810, 1815, 1815, 1510, 1510, 1512, 1512]
```